# Gradle Run Task Even If Build Fails

Tags: gradle, groovy

So I'm trying to print some stuff to the console in Gradle even if the build fails. How can I do this?

I've found `build.finalizedBy(taskName)` but that only runs if the build finishes normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either [`gradle.buildFinished`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle.html#org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle:buildFinished(org.gradle.api.Action)) or a finalizer task (as you mentioned).

In your example, `build.finalizedBy(taskName)` will only execute `taskName` if the `build` task executes.  If the build fails before the `build` task executes, `taskName` won't be executed.

e.g., this prints a message based on the result of the build:

```
gradle.buildFinished { result ->
   if (result.failure) {
      logger.lifecycle("build failed")
   } else {
      logger.lifecycle("build successful")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can let any build continue on task failures by using the `--continue` parameter on Gradle invocation. If you do not want to type this parameter all the time you can use the following code in your `settings.gradle`:

```
startParameter.continueOnFailure = true
```

Please note that other tasks may fail due to an earlier task that failed. Using this option, tasks connected via `finalizedBy` will be executed, but you should only use this option if the tasks are related, even for non-failure cases.

Of course, you can also use lifecycle listeners of the [`Gradle`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle.html) object or its [`TaskExecutionGraph`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraph.html). You can use

- [`afterTask`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraph.html#afterTask(groovy.lang.Closure))
- a full [`TaskExecutionListener`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionListener.html) implementation
- [`buildFinished`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/invocation/Gradle.html#buildFinished(groovy.lang.Closure)) (for the whole build)